How to move many repositories from the internal network Git to the company server GitLab at once?
All.
We have two git environment.

internal network git (NAS + git)
NAS with gitlab (NAS + gitlab)

Our company use NAS with git. then we can clone repository to SourceTree using SSH.
But to secure our souce, we change the system. That is NAS with gitlab.
This is question.
How to migration(or mirror) to gitlab at once?
We use git push --mirror to move one repository.
But We want to move at once.
Thank you. and have a nice day All.
Regards
before, i refer to this post
How to clone all projects of a group at once in GitLab?
but our nas can't use internet.... this is security internal sever.
